Scaling both an object and its position
Is it possible to scale an object and adjust its position accordingly?
I've got an annoying situation where the scene unit scale was 1.0 and I needed to change it to 0.001 for millimeters. However when I scale the objects by 1000 in the scene their positions don't adjust so they all end up on the center axis since the position locations become very small values. This messes up positions of objects used for boolean operations and alignment of parts (there are many objects to adjust).

EDIT: I do realize I could manually scale each of the position values by 1000, I'm hoping there is an easier way as there are around 100 objects in the scene

"their positions don't adjust so they all end up on the center axis since the position locations become very small values" Can you elaborate more in detail what this means? If you just scaled down and then up after that it should be the original again, right? So something must have happened inbetween. Also your gif is nice but not very helpful i fear. Where are these letters supposed to be, what booleans? Maybe you are just looking for this option https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/individual_origins.html

When the 3D cursor is at the world center (0, 0, 0) and if you then select all objects and set the Transform Pivot Point to 3D cursor, scaling by 1000 will then also scale the locations outwards from the center by 1000.
